AWS Cloudfront with lambda at edge failing
I'm trying to create a very simple frontend with AWS S3, AWS Cloudfront and an AWS Lambda at edge for protection. The frontend is very simple and contains no sensitive information (I just don't want to share it publically yet) so no need to integrate with Cognito at this point.
I have the following stack:
export class MainStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const siteName = "mySite";

    const bucket = new s3.Bucket(this, "frontend", {
      bucketName: `${cdk.Stack.of(this).stackName.toLowerCase()}-${siteName}-frontend`,
      blockPublicAccess: s3.BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL,
      accessControl: s3.BucketAccessControl.PRIVATE,
      enforceSSL: true,
      removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
      autoDeleteObjects: true,
      publicReadAccess: false,
    });
    new CfnOutput(this, "Bucket", { value: bucket.bucketName });

    const authFunction = new cloudfront.experimental.EdgeFunction(
      this,
      "authFunction",
      {
        handler: "authorizer.handler",
        runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_20_X,
        code: lambda.Code.fromAsset("src/lambdas/authorizer.zip"),
        currentVersionOptions: {
          removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
        },
        timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(5),
      },
    );

    const distribution = new cloudfront.Distribution(
      this,
      "frontendCloudfrontDistribution",
      {
        defaultRootObject: "index.html",
        minimumProtocolVersion: cloudfront.SecurityPolicyProtocol.TLS_V1_2_2021,
        defaultBehavior: {
          origin: origins.S3BucketOrigin.withOriginAccessControl(bucket),
          compress: true,
          allowedMethods: cloudfront.AllowedMethods.ALLOW_GET_HEAD,
          viewerProtocolPolicy: cloudfront.ViewerProtocolPolicy.ALLOW_ALL,
          cachePolicy: CachePolicy.CACHING_DISABLED,
          edgeLambdas: [
            {
              functionVersion: authFunction.currentVersion,
              eventType: LambdaEdgeEventType.VIEWER_REQUEST,
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    );
    new CfnOutput(this, "DistributionId", {
      value: distribution.distributionId,
    });

    new s3deploy.BucketDeployment(this, "DeployWithInvalidation", {
      sources: [s3deploy.Source.asset(path.join(__dirname, "../frontend"))],
      destinationBucket: bucket,
      distribution,
      distributionPaths: ["/*"],
    });
  }
}

The CDK deploys fine and looks OK to me. The lambda itself works fine if I test it directly in the console. If I remove the lambda from the CDK stack then the frontend is also accessible as expected so it seems the Lambda doesn't work nicely at this point with Cloudfront.
When I try to access it with Postman (I actually use Bruno, the free alternative) I get the following result:
502 ERROR

The request could not be satisfied.

The Lambda function returned an invalid request or response to CloudFront. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.

If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.

I think this is because I don't return the right headers or something. My Lambda code:
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  const authorizationHeader = event?.request?.headers?.authorization;
  const preferredAuthorization = "Basic someBase64String";

  if (authorizationHeader?.value === preferredAuthorization) {
    console.log("Logged in");
    return event.request;
  }

  console.log("Unauthorized");
  return {
    statusCode: 401,
    statusDescription: "Unauthorized",
    headers: {
      "www-authenticate": [{ value: 'Basic realm="Enter your credentials"' }],
    },
  };
};

Does anyone see why this fails?

What is in Lambda@Edge logs?

I finally found the problem: I needed to return the status (not statusCode) as a string instead of a number.
